# Based on user position, hide rows in table -5 and +5 after name (jquery)

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

Looking for some jquery help with this scenario...

I am displaying a list of sports rankings on a page with a table that could potentially contain a couple of thousand players. For display purposes, I only want to show the five rows before and the five rows after the currently logged in user.

For example, if I had a table with this info:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Person 1</td><td>999</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 2</td><td>998</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 3</td><td>997</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 4</td><td>994</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 5</td><td>992</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 6</td><td>980</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 7</td><td>970</td></tr>
<tr><td class="me">Person 8</td><td>960</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 9</td><td>950</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 10</td><td>940</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 11</td><td>930</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 12</td><td>920</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 13</td><td>910</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 14</td><td>900</td></tr>
<tr><td>Person 15</td><td>890</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm logged in as Person 8. So I should only see the rows from Person 3 to Person 13.

I'm hoping to find a solution using something like a loop with jquery's prev() and next() functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of your jQuery code if you already have some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of indexes here, check this code... ([preview on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/SGnEx/3/))

```
// First we get the index of the row containing the user
var me_tr_index = $('tr')
    .index($('tr')
        .filter( function (){ 
            return $('td.me', this).length;
        })
    );

// Now we have our index, we can use it inside conditions
$('tr').each( function (i) {
    if(i < me_tr_index -2 || i > me_tr_index +2)
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    if(i === me_tr_index )
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

Comment: You don't need to find the index within the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/); simply use `each(function(i) { // i is the index })`. Incidentally, why are you throwing your variables into the global scope (by omitting the `var` declaration)?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

Disable display for all "tr", and place the class on the "tr" rather than the "td" element.

```
    myindex = $('tr').index($('.me'));
    if(myindex>=0){
        for(i=(myindex*1-5);i<=(myindex*1+5);i++){
            if(i>=0){$('tr').eq(i).show();}
        }
    }
    else{console.log("You are not there.")}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd offer a plain JavaScript solution:

```
// to avoid explicitly iterating through parentNodes:
HTMLElement.prototype.closest = function (tagName) {
    tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
    var self = this,
        selfTag = self.tagName.toLowerCase();
    return selfTag == tagName ? self : self.parentNode.closest(tagName);
}

function borders (target, distance) {
    var self = target,
        tr = self.closest('tr'),
        centre = tr.rowIndex,
        tbody = tr.closest('tbody'),
        rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        min = centre - parseInt(distance,10),
        max = centre + parseInt(distance,10);
    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        rows[i].style.display = (i > min - 1) && (i < max + 1) ? 'table-row' : 'none';
    }

}

var me = document.querySelector('.me');
borders(me, 5);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TSjA4/).

As well as a simple jQuery alternative:

```
var meIndex = $('.me').closest('tr').index();

$('tr').hide().filter(function (i) {
    return i >= (meIndex - 5) && i <= (meIndex + 5);
}).show();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TSjA4/1/).

References:

- jQuery methods:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_Documention/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirect=no).
  - [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex).
  - [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName).
  - [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).